# How to delete a char pointer in c++

Tags: c++

So if i declare the following code

```
int main() {
   char* c = new char[20];
   delete c;
   return 0;
}
```

Why is it that I get no memory leak? Isn't the correct way to delete

```
delete[] c;
```

Both ways work and I get no memory leak in either.

Comment: When causing undefined behavior, one should not be surprised that something that wasn't defined happens.

Comment: Why do you say the first way worked? You wrote it. You expected it to give a memory leak. It didn't. Since it didn't do what the author expected, in what sense can you describe that as working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way *doesn't* work. It just *sort of looks like* it works.

This is known as [*Undefined Behaviour*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub): C++ doesn't hold your hand if you do something wrong. It allows the compiler to assume you don't make certain kinds of mistakes, because checking for these mistakes would slow your program down.

If you write Undefined Behaviour, your program could do **anything**. Including:

- Crash
- Give odd results
- Crash or give odd results only occasionally
- Appearing to work perfectly
- [Make demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

"Appearing to work perfectly" is actually the *worst* of these, because you don't realise you have a bug. Until for instance you port to a different platform, or get a new compiler release, or something else changes, and *then* you start getting odd results, but of course, this piece of code has worked for years, so it can't possibly be your code that is wrong... can it?

Good compilers will complain about some of these types of mistakes anyway, even though they aren't required to, especially if you turn on extra warnings. Also, *static analysis* tools can help you catch more of these errors. (Just search for that term; making recommendations would be explicitly off-topic here).

Comment: no I am using Visual studio and using  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
to test for memory leaks....and it returns no errors

Comment: @YusufJama Yes, like I said, it **looks liike** it works! That is a perfectly valid thing for the program to do when you commit Undefined Behaviour. It might be that in your particular implementation, `delete` and `delete[]` are similar enough that this is safe. But do you want to bet on that? Just write the correct code, since you even already know how to do that.

Comment: i think actually since it's primitive datatype, then it will work. if it's an array of objects, this will def cause a memory leak....maybe i am wrong?

Comment: @YusufJama You still don't get the "Undefined" part of Undefined Behavior. The phrase says it all.

Comment: @YusufJama You are wrong. Using `delete` when you need `delete[]` is **always** 100% incorrect. It just might **appear** to work.

Comment: i agree with what you are saying...if you use new, then use delete. If you use new [], then use delete []. It's just there was no error popping up so I assumed it was working. Looks like I have to look into undefined behaviour

Comment: @YusufJama Yes, it can be a bit tricky. The whole purpose is that the compiler doesn't have to put in extra checks for programming mistakes, because these checks would cost you performance every time you run your program. Good static analysis tools can catch most of them.

Comment: @YusufJama *i think actually since it's primitive datatype, then it will work.* -- No, this is incorrect thinking.  In C++, `new / new []` and `delete / delete []` can be overloaded.  Overloading may involve doing extra checks to see if the wrong form of `delete` is called and if so, assert() or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways won't work. If you allocate an array using new [], you have to delete it using delete []. Period. It is undefined behavior otherwise.

Note: If the first way compiles and runs, it doesn't mean it is working. It is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. Your program might crash. It might not. Nothing can be said definitively.

Comment: no I am using Visual studio and using  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
to test for memory leaks....and it returns no errors

Comment: @YusufJama One outcome of Undefined Behaviour is looking like it works. Right up until suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: it checks for memory leaks, and if there any detected, it will display in the console...

Comment: And that is one of the outcomes of Undefined Behavior, you see. This is the reason why it is called so. On my sytem it shows memory leak when running with valgrind.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is the nuttiest stuff. Leads to all sorts of Heisenbugs.